# How to make a SCSI-3 terminator?

Tags: termination

I have an old VAXstation that has an external SCSI Bus.

When I don't have anything attached to that, I get errors. I was thinking of adding a terminator, but those that I found online are quite expensive. So I was thinking of wiring one myself.

Does anybody happen to know how I should wire them, and what resistors I need?

Answer (score 3):

All the answers and information you need are on the [Wikipedia page about Parallel SCSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_SCSI)

It mentions that SCSI-3 requires active termination instead of passive.

It then goes on to talk about termination:

> **Active termination** means that there is a small voltage regulator which provides a +3.3 V supply. Each signal line is then terminated by a \$110\Omega\$ resistor to the +3.3 V supply. Active termination provides a better impedance match than passive termination because most flat ribbon cables have a characteristic impedance of approximately \$110\Omega\$.

Comment: OK, I'll look into it, once I get all my parts.